# What are the effects of the food items?

Tags: guwange

In some situations in Guwange, food (health recovery) items seem to give me much less health than at other times, and sometimes they give me no health at all. I've read a few guides about the game, but none of them go into full detail about how the items work, and some of the information seems to be conflicting.

How exactly do the food items work, and where can I find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's remember that the overall life bar is divided up into three equal segments; this is important, especially for understanding the small food item.

[image: Picture of life bar]

[image: Small food item] **Small food item:** Restores up to 1/2 of a single partially-damaged life segment; that is, one that is not completely empty, and not completely full. It will only fill that segment to its maximum, and any overflow will be wasted.

If you don't have any partially-filled life segments (i.e., you have exactly one, two, or three full segments), you will receive no health benefit. Instead, if your life bar is completely full, you will receive a +2000 bonus to your chain counter, and if you have one or two full blocks, you will receive a +1000 bonus.

Dropped from destroying the large statue in stage 3, dropped from the tank near the end of stage 5, and dropped by a spider in stage 6. Also dropped from every ox-cart that you destroy near the end of stage 6 without using a bomb.

[image: Medium food item] **Medium food item:** Restores the equivalent of one full life bar segment, and it can cross over the boundary between segments, unlike the small food item.

If your life bar is completely full, you will receive +3000 to your chain instead.

Dropped if you defeat the stage 4 mid-boss without using a bomb, dropped by a spider in stage 6, and dropped by destroying the right-hand burning tree during the first phase of the final boss.

[image: Large food item] **Large food item:** Restores your life bar completely.

If your life bar is completely full, you will receive +4000 to your chain instead.

Dropped by a spider in stage 6.